# Recurse through a dictionary to rearrange items

Tags: c#, recursion

I hope this description will suffice, the best way to put it in words is just giving an example of what it is now and how I want it to be. Here goes.

When I execute a certain method, a structure will be generated. Which may have the following content:

```
> Key: FaceBook, Value: Dinges 
> Key: SocialMedia, Value: FaceBook 
> Key: Medium, Value: SocialMedia
```

These are associations. According to this Dinges is associated with FaceBook, Facebook is associated with SocialMedia and SocialMedia is associated with Medium.

Now, what I actually need is the following layout:

```
> Key: FaceBook, Value: Dinges 
> Key: SocialMedia, Value: FaceBook 
> Key: SocialMedia, Value: Dinges 
> Key: Medium, Value: SocialMedia 
> Key: Medium, Value: Facebook 
> Key: Medium, Value: Dinges
```

I actually have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code that you're currently using?

Comment: First of all, you can't use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for that because you'll have duplicate keys.

Comment: And also state the data type of the keys and values, as it *appears* you have multiple duplicating keys.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's just to illustrate my question. They are just strings.

Comment: @Oxymoron it doesn't help the illustration because that is not physically possible with the generic dictionary.

Comment: Fixed it, using a dictionary is no requirement at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, basically, you want to create the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of your source dictionary. If you don't have any loops in your dictionary, a simple algorithm creating a new `List<Tuple<string, string>>` could look like this:

```
for each pair (key, value) in your dictionary:
    do
        list.add(key, value)
        if value is not a key in the dictionary, break loop
        value = dictionary(value)
    loop
```

**EDIT2**: Since it's quite easy to translate in C#, here you are:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // base data
dic.Add("FaceBook", "Dingens");
dic.Add("SocialMedia", "FaceBook");
dic.Add("Medium", "SocialMedia");

var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();  // result

foreach (var de in dic)
{
    var value = de.Value;
    do
    {
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(de.Key, value));
    } while (dic.TryGetValue(value, out value));
}

foreach (var x in list)
    Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + ": " + x.Item2);
```

Comment: Not entirely accurate, it can only have one type associated with each key.  That type could be a class with many values.  Either way, the dictionary usage is still not ideal.  Good catch on the underlying requirement.

Comment: Yeah it does feel like it has bearing in transitivity as a -> b,  b -> c and a -> c. Im looking into that. Specifying the dictionary structure was wrong, forgot keys had to be unique.

Comment: @Oxymoron: I've added a simple algorithm to my answer that should do what you want.

Comment: @Oxymoron: Added a C# sample.

Comment: Very nice, i have encountered transitivity during a set theory course,  no closures yet though. Nice to see it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that you want to generate a cartesian product out of the input you have.

Maybe the following article can provide you more input on your problem

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Comment: It is not a Cartesian product.